# Logging custom request headers with AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

What is the best way to log custom HTTP headers like `X-Foo: bar` received by CloudFront?

I haven't tried Real-time logs, but Standard access logs seem to log only the [pre-defined set of fields/headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#LogFileFormat). My custom ones do not show up in there.

Currently I am thinking of leveraging CloudFront Functions for some custom logging. Is there any better (more easy/efficient) approach?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you need to log this at the network edge rather than at your web server? Web server logging would seem to be a simple way to do this, if you're using a web server. If you're using S3 or similar as a source it might not be practical. Perhaps you could edit your question to give more context.

CloudFront functions can log to [Cloudwatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-logs.html). If you need to log at the edge that seems like a reasonable option.

Comment: Edge logging is required simply because most requests _do not reach_ the source (which is indeed the purpose of the edge!). Besides, the source is S3 indeed. Good to know re cf functions->cloudwatch logs, thank you.